# The URI given to MediaControl for a music file's album art .Net

Tags: c#, windows-8, uri, media

I want to show album art in the windows 8 media control, like this:

[image: AlbumArt]

However, MediaControl.AlbumArt has type Uri, instead of type ImageSource like I expected. Does the album art embedded in a music file even have a URI? I've tried providing a URI to the file ("file:///C:/Rest/Of/Path.mp3") (an immediate exception results), but other than that I don't even know where to start. Maybe I'm supposed to write the album art to a temporary file and point at that (feels like the wrong way to do it, but maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

You can either provide a web link or use the ms-appx:// format to refer to files in your app directory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx

Note that to reference the root of your app directory it's three slashes:

```
var x = new Uri("ms-appx:///path/to/image.png");
```

Comment: The music files aren't on the web or in my app directory, they're in the user's music folder.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Maybe I shouldn't answer questions late at night. If the art is embedded (missed that yesterday) it looks like you're gonna have to copy it to a temp file. You might also want to check that you've declared music library permissions if you want to access files in code.